# ID and EAN inheritance may violate Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a design question for my application.

I have a product and a category. Both must have an ID.

Category can have any positive integer as an ID. (-> Id-class)

Product must have an positive integer between 8 & 13 ciphers as an ID. (-> Ean-class)

Since that's the only thing these classes do (create an id) and a getter/setter with the correct check.

To reduce code (DRY) I let Ean inherit from Id. But won't that violate Liskov (LSP)?

My question:

1. Is my LSP-reasoning correct?
   If yes:
2. Should I solve it with creating an interface? (seems like duplicate code) Or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Identifier.java

```
public class Identifier {

    private Long id = 1000000000000L;

    public Identifier(){

    }

    public Identifier(Long id){
        setId(id);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Ean.java

```
public class Ean extends Identifier {

    private final static int MIN_AMOUNT_OF_CIPHERS = 8;

    private final static int MAX_AMOUNT_OF_CIPHERS = 13;

    private final static String ERROR_EAN_LENGTH = "err_ean_length";

    public Ean() {
    }

    public Ean(Long ean) throws DomainException {
        setEan(ean);
    }

    public Long getEan() {
        return getId();
    }

    public void setEan(Long ean) throws DomainException {
        if (String.valueOf(ean).length() < MIN_AMOUNT_OF_CIPHERS
                || String.valueOf(ean).length() > MAX_AMOUNT_OF_CIPHERS) {
            throw new DomainException(ERROR_EAN_LENGTH);
        }
        setId(ean);
}
```

Comment: setEan() and getEan() should not exist. You should override setId() instead. Otherwise, anybody can call setId(12L) on an Ean and thus store an invalid value in it. You shouldn't call an overridable method from a constructor either.

Comment: Identifiers should be immutable IMHO.

Comment: All right, now setEan() & getEan() are the get/setId().So you should create a seperate method to do the check of the EAN? Or else you'll have twice the check (in constructor and in the setter)?

Comment: Not an answer for the LSP question, but an EAN really shouldn't be modeled as a number anyway.  It is a numeric string with length and checksum restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my LSP-reasoning correct?

Answer: no

It looks like any place an Id is accepted, an Ean instance would be valid, right? That's what LSP is all about. That's because Ean is a subset of valid Id's. Any Ean is a valid Id but the opposite isn't always true.

> Should I solve it with creating an interface? (seems like duplicate
>   code) Or is there another solution?

You could have an interface and two specific implementations (Id and Ean). I would probably do that, because for me there's not reason to make Ean subclass Id. Both could implement a single interface aimed to serve as a identifier unit.

**EDIT:** 
The problem in your inheritance model is that an Ean instance could be inconsistent if you call setId() method inherited from parent class.